# Prove space of lipschiz contiuous functions is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $E=C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, i.e. continuous real functions on $[0,1]$ with the norm of $f\in E$ : $||f||=max_xf(x)$.

Let $K\subset E$ be the subspace of functions $f$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ and $f$ 1-lipschitz continuous. Prove that $K$ is compact in $E$.

Could someone give me a clue... I don't know how to deal with the lipschitz continuity to construct a convergent sequence.

Thanks a lot~

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: @BernardWojcik Thanks so much :)